# Excel text data into R

Tags: r, text, import

I've been researching into this question, which I assume should be easy to fix, but am not having any luck. I have an excel file where each cell is some text of variable length. I'm wanting to read this into R so I can eventually do some text classification, but am failing. I get errors when using read.table and am struggling with all other alternatives. I've never worked with text data before so perhaps this is my issue. Having problems finding good examples of importing text data into R when it isn't in a corpus format.

Comment: check `xlsx` package but I think it only works for versions of Excel <=2007

Answer (score 3):

There are special packages for reading data from the excel format. I mostly use `readxl` when I need to do this, but I know that there are several (a lot of them are described in [this tutorial by datacamp](http://blog.datacamp.com/r-data-import-tutorial/), in the section Importing Excel files into R).

Another possibility (assuming you are using windows) is to copy the cells to the clipboard and use

```
read.table("clipboard")
```

for macOS and Linux there are similar commands, but I don't know them by heart.

Comment: Then there is the export from Excel as CSV option followed by `read.csv`

Comment: While that is certainly an option, I find that my hard drive gets cluttered with csv-files after a while, and I don't know which ones are up-to-date. I prefer to work directly with the excel-file.

Comment: The package [xlsx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf) may also be of use.